# What does "Debugger function entry" value mean, in WinDbg .fnent output?

Tags: windbg

I'm learning a web article [X64 Deep Dive](https://codemachine.com/articles/x64_deep_dive.html), and I have a small question.

What does "Debugger function entry" value mean, in WinDbg `.fnent` output? It seems that, in one WinDbg session, whatever target function I inspect, the value is always **00000244`04becd38**, as depicted in my screenshot.

A simple googling does not reveal the answer, so I ask it here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the address will be same for a session of windbg

if you quit and start a new windbg session the address will be different

```
C:\>cdb -c ".fnent NtCreateFile;.fnent NtOpenFile;.fnent kernelbase!CreateProcessA;q" cdb | grep -i Debug.*fu
Debugger function entry 00000216`fa861c78 for:
Debugger function entry 00000216`fa861c78 for:
Debugger function entry 00000216`fa861c78 for:

C:\>cdb -c ".fnent NtCreateFile;.fnent NtOpenFile;.fnent kernelbase!CreateProcessA;q" cdb | grep -i Debug.*fu
Debugger function entry 00000250`a81293a8 for:
Debugger function entry 00000250`a81293a8 for:
Debugger function entry 00000250`a81293a8 for:

C:\>cdb -c ".fnent NtCreateFile;.fnent NtOpenFile;.fnent kernelbase!CreateProcessA;q" cdb | grep -i Debug.*fu
Debugger function entry 00000261`4c677948 for:
Debugger function entry 00000261`4c677948 for:
Debugger function entry 00000261`4c677948 for:
```

it is the address of a part of cache named FunctionEntryCache Maintained by DbgHelp

the address will be in the heap of debugger